# How to get admob in webview?

Tags: android, webview, admob

I have a web page that I load via webView. Page has a div block to show an advertize and my task is get this div blok and insert code for adMob. Unfortunatly I doesn't found any docs that describes this approach or even says that it is possible.

If you know something that can help me I will be glad to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to show an AdMob advert within a WebView widget which itself is in some other layout container in your layout?  My first instinct is to ask "why?"  AdMob recommends that you use AdSense for web pages, which is what you essentially seem to be describing.

Answer (score -1):

First advice: do not use webview  unless you are forced to.

To display an as in an application, do not use the web one, but an AdView (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid)

```
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Place your AdView below your Webview and voila!

Comment: Thanks, I know how to wotk with AdView but client want to do this via web page. He has a complex pages and think about an oportunity to shows them on mobile with an adMob

Comment: If client wants to create crappy app and break admobs guidelines, you won't find any help here.

Comment: May be it is possible to load some javascript which change div block to code that shows adMob? Does it possible?

Comment: Admob ads can be displayed in HTML from server side, I don't understand where it gets complicated and why you need to modify the code...